# How to insert files above every line with a variable in sed?

Tags: sed

I have a file with this values:

```
[mik@mikypc ~]$ cat file.txt 
id=cat8760004
id=cat1350003
id=cat9020002
```

And I want to insert id with the value above every line, so the result will be:

```
New_id=cat8760004
id=cat8760004
New_id=cat1350003
id=cat1350003
New_id=cat9020002
id=cat9020002
```

How could I do that?, I have tried with sed, but I cannot replace the variable:

```
[mik@mikypc ~]$ cat file.txt | sed '/cat\([0-9][0-9]*\)/ i\New_id &'
New_id &
id=cat8760004
New_id &
id=cat1350003
New_id &
id=cat9020002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/.*/New_&\n&/' file.txt
```

Output:

```
New_id=cat8760004
id=cat8760004
New_id=cat1350003
id=cat1350003
New_id=cat9020002
id=cat9020002
```